# Работа с фрагментами

Tags: android-fragment, android-sdk, android

Доброго дня! В общем, ситуация следующая. Нужно сделать форму для заполнения данными, которая состоит из 7 экранов. Суть заключается в следующем: нужно сделать, чтобы я между ними ходил вперед и назад, при этом данные сохранялись. Сделать это нужно с использованием фрагментов.   Может кто подсказать идею, как это можно реализовать, или направить в нужном направлении?

Comment: google, fragment, android

Comment: Простите, думаете, я это не делал? Просто мне скучно и я сюда пишу?

Comment: @Bjick, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Удалите просто тему, да дело с концом. Разберусь как-нибудь.

Comment: Может быть, попробовать добавить `addToBackStack()`, чтобы можно было вернуться к предыдущему фрагменту по нажатию кнопки `назад`? Или попробовать сохранять данные в настройках?  
Как я понимаю, есть форма, на ней 7 кнопочек (или др. элементов), по нажатию открывается новый фрагмент, в котором нужно заполнить какие-то поля, закрыть и потом (если надо), вернуться туда? Так?

Comment: Либо спроектировать класс, который будет висеть в памяти и содержать в себе значения полей. Например: Класс Автомобиль. который содержит в себе такие поля как : руль, колеса, корпус. И по мере заполнения формы в этот класс инициализируется руль, колеса, корпус. Потом, как ты закрываешь форму для заполнения (руль, например), поле `руль` хранится в классе Автомобиль. И если ты хочешь открыть заново форму `руль` то данные берёшь уже из класса Автомобиль

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, тоже пришел к такому же варианту.

Answer (score 1):

Направлю более точно.
1. startandroid.ru - там читаем про фрагменты все, что можно.
2. Для прокручивания экранов хорошо бы использовать android.support.v4.view.ViewPager, в гугле уроков можно найти немало. Также можно при этом спрятать android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip (а можно и не прятать). Правда, идея может быть не совсем адекватная, но, имхо, я так бы и сделал (p.s. сам я новичок).
3. Для сохранения содержимого фрагмента я использовал

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}
```

Опять же, про ViewPager много уроков, там я нашел ответы почти на все свои вопросы касательно данной темы.

Comment: Мне не нужен вью пейджер, мне просто нужно реализовать грамотное хождение между фрагментами с сохранением данных. Что касается самих фрагментов, я почитал, но идея хорошей реализации от этого не появилась.

Comment: А чем вам хождение между фрагментами при помощи ViewPager'а не угодило?) Просто используете свайпы влево и вправо, при этом данные фрагментов еще и сохраняются.
Ну, мое дело предложить, ваше - отказаться. Удачи с поиском других альтернатив, если найдете - отпишитесь, самому интересно, что накопаете)

Comment: Дело не в том, что мне не угодило. Дело в поставленной задаче.

Answer (score 0):

Направляю в нужном направлении (ц) - начните с google "Урок 104. Android 3. Fragments. Lifecycle"